# Jenkins triggered code deploy is not including subdirectories while creating the zip file

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-code-deploy

The directory structure of my jenkins workspace is this -

```
|- appspec.yml
|- afterInstall.sh
|---
   |codebase
```

The problem is that zip being prepared is not containing the codebase directory.

Following is a screenshot of what I have enetered in the "Deploy an application to AWS CodeDeploy" section of Jenkins -

[image]

I checked that there is a Subdirectory option there, which reads -

> A subdirectory inside the workspace to be packed instead of the whole
>   workspace. Remember that the appspec.yml must be placed at the top of
>   the .zip archive. The excludes and includes will be applied based on
>   this path.

But, that does not seem to be what I am looking for, since I want to include the subdirectory in addition to all the files that are present in the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emptying the "Include files" option worked!

I was complicating things..